# Adding custom post formatting options in custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, tinymce

I've added custom post formatting options using the below code -

```
function wpb_mce_buttons_2($buttons) {
    array_unshift($buttons, 'styleselect');
    return $buttons;
}
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'wpb_mce_buttons_2');

 function my_mce_before_init_insert_formats( $init_array ) 
 {

// Define the style_formats array

    $style_formats = array(
        // Each array child is a format with it's own settings
        array(
            'title' => 'Post Title Block',
            'block' => 'div',
            'classes' => 'post-title-block',
            'wrapper' => true,

        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Post Content Block',
            'block' => 'div',
            'classes' => 'post-content-block',
            'wrapper' => true,
        ),

        array(
            'title' => 'Important',
            'block' => 'div',
            'classes' => 'important-content-block',
            'wrapper' => true,
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Image center',
            'block' => 'div',
            'classes' => 'img-center-post',
            'wrapper' => true,
        ),
                array(
                        'title' => 'Program number',
                        'block' => 'div',
                        'classes' => 'program-num',
                        'wrapper' => true,
                ),
    );
    // Insert the array, JSON ENCODED, into 'style_formats'
    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );

    return $init_array;
}
// Attach callback to 'tiny_mce_before_init'
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_before_init_insert_formats' );
```

I have 2 **custom post types**. I want the custom post formatting options to appear in only one of the custom post type. How can I do it?

I've tried using `if ( !(get_post_type() == 'mech_tuts') )` inside

```
function my_mce_before_init_insert_formats( $init_array )
```

definition where `mech_tuts` is the post type but that gave unexpected results. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's too late, but I found out how to solve this so I think I could share my solution.
You have to access the global $post variable to find out the post type:

```
function haet_custom_toolbar( $initArray ) {  
    global $post;
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );

    if( 'page' == $post_type ){
        $initArray['toolbar1'] = 'formatselect,styleselect,|,bold,italic,|,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,|,pastetext,removeformat,|,undo,redo,|,bullist,numlist,|,link,unlink,|,spellchecker,fullscreen';
        $initArray['toolbar2'] = '';    
    }else if( 'product' == $post_type ){
        $initArray['toolbar1'] = 'pastetext,removeformat,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,|,code';
        $initArray['toolbar2'] = '';    
    }

    return $initArray;  
} 
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'haet_custom_toolbar' );
```

Here's a blog post about it containing all available buttons for the WordPress editor: [Customize WordPress Editor for WooCommerce Products](http://etzelstorfer.com/en/customize-wordpress-editor-for-woocommerce-products/)